# How to check what shared libraries are linked when I run a interpreted language binary and its script?

Tags: python, lua, shared-libraries, libraries, interpreted-language

I am trying to find every library that is actually needed to run a lua script that requires torch libraries

**test.lua**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

print "Welcome to LUA"
print('_VERSION = ' .. _VERSION)
require("nn") -- this loads torch nn libraries to be further used in the code
print "Load pass"
```

**Output**:

```
Welcome to LUA
_VERSION = Lua 5.1
Load pass
```

When I use

```
lld ./lua
# or
lld ./lua test.lua
```

I get the following output:

```
ldd ./lua ../../../bin/test.lua
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdba77d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f160dd3e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f160db3a000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f160d8f3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f160d52a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005580e2ebd000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f160d301000)
../../../bin/test.lua:
    not a dynamic executable
```

Obviously the libraries used by torch nn are not displayed here. We only see the necessary libraries to the "lua" program

If make the `test.lua` an executable file and I run `ldd ./test.lua`, I get the following output

```
ldd ./test.lua 
    not a dynamic executable
```

How to check what libraries (or .so) are linked when I run a interpreted language binary and its script? (in Lua and in Python)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767135/how-can-i-list-modules-and-check-functions-exist-at-the-command-line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LD_DEBUG`:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all python tmp.py 2>&1 | grep 'generating link map'
3358:   file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  generating link map
3358:   file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
3358:   file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
3358:   file=libutil.so.1 [0];  generating link map
3358:   file=libz.so.1 [0];  generating link map
3358:   file=libm.so.6 [0];  generating link map
```

Keep in mind that if your app only loads library on particular event, you may not see it during default run.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most probably Lua is loading `nn` dynamically. It looks for `nn` in `LUA_CPATH` or `package.cpath`.

One way to find which libraries are being required is to redefine `require`:

```
local real_require=require
function require(x)
    print(x,package.searchpath(x,package.cpath))
    return real_require(x)
end
```

Comment: I agree with you. It is being loaded dynamically from LUA_PATH (nn was a bad example as it did not have a matching .so). But it performs several other `require ("libraries")` that have corresponding .so. Those libraries that are being loaded from LUA_CPATH, but I want to know exactly which of those libraries are loaded.
Is it possible to check the dynamically linked libraries? If so, how do I do this on an interpreted script?

Comment: I got a problem where it complains on the searchpath function. Does package.searchpath requires any "includes"

Comment: @ElectricGoat, you need Lua 5.2 or later for that, sorry.